# CMD - Ping and traceroute from list of ips

Tags: batch-file

We have sporadic connection failures when webserver tries to connect to service on the net.
There is a problem to trace failure from PHP for many reasons.

I'm a web-programmer and not familiar with command-line scripts. Can anyone help with following cmd-script:
-there is a list of ips separated by newline in text file (ip_list.txt)
-take ip from list and ping it, if it fails on first attempt - traceroute it
-go to next ip in file

Comment: If there is anything specific that you have tried, please edit your question to include it. As it currently stands, your question is too broad to be considered on-topic.

Comment: Yep. I tried tracrouting from PHP as stated above. I can only add that it was created through sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really sure what you want to test, but here's a pretty useful command to test ping. 
Enter `ping IP_ADDRESS -l 10 -n 10` directly to cmd, change the IP_ADDRESS to ip address you want. 
`-l 10` - Ping you ip address with 10 bytes of data
`-n 10` - Ping for 10 times
`ping /?` - For more informations 
To get each ip address (line by line) in a text file, use `for /f %%a in (YOUR_FILE.txt) do ( //to do )`. Since I'm not sure about what you want, so that's all I can help with :)

Comment: Thanks!  Can we distinguish status of ping (timeout) and run another command?

Comment: for /f %%a in (YOUR_FILE.txt) do (
*IF (TIMEOUT) tracert IP*
)

Comment: Maybe i'm doing it wrong. The problem is that there are sporadic connection fails. And we want to find out where failing occures.

Comment: You mean you want to use tracert ip to troubleshoot?

Comment: Yep. I want to use tracert to find out where connection is lost.

Comment: `tracert -h 10 IP_ADDRESS`, `-h 10` - max hops to search for target, `tracert /?` - for more informations